Claude 3 Haiku connection/implementation issue
I am attempting to connect AWS Bedrock to a NextJS app.  I am just trying to get a working response, but I keep running into hurdles.  I can't seem to get past my current error:

Error generating chat response: Error: No value provided for input HTTP label: modelId.

Below is my code. Am I missing something stupid and obvious?
import { BedrockClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-bedrock";
import { InvokeModelCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-bedrock-runtime";


const client = new BedrockClient({
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  },
});

export const generateChatResponse = async (messages) =>
  const params = {
    Input: {
      Text: messages.map((msg) => msg.content).join("\n"),
    },
    ModelId: "claude-3-haiku",
  };

  try {
    const command = new InvokeModelCommand(params);
   
    const response = await client.send(command);
    return response;

  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error generating chat response:", error);
    return null;
  }
};

